# Spring Boot app with custom React form and LDAP authorization returns status 302 when submitting credentials

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

In our project we implement frontend with React i.e. integrate into jar-file static html with packed React js-file. Backend is Spring Boot + Spring Security. 
App has authorization form which is done by addressing to LDAP.

If I strip spring security configuration down to the basics, ie Boot opens its own basic login form then authorization works fine

But when I try to integrate custom login form then form shows but I fail with 302 response (Tomcat provided by Boot). I do not even hit the breakpoint in the class providing Ldap authorization ... so it sounds extra strange why status is 302 if authorization attempt did not happen.

I would highly appreciate any advice.

The relevant part of the WORKING config without React GUI:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
@Autowired
private MoAuthenticationSuccessHandler moAuthenticationSuccessHandler;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(moAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
}
```

and the variant when I involve React form:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(moAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
}
plus
 @Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer adapter() {

    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("index.html");

        }...
```

- Declaring `.loginPage("/login")` substitutes default login page  and makes me responsible for providing the page serving that url - via registering `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("index.html")` I make React form responsible for this.
- `loginProcessingUrl("/login")` is a kinda REST endpoint which accepts data from the form if the form has `action` attribute looking at `"/login"` as well

Thank you in advance

Comment: Apologies I was answering multiple SO questions earlier and mixed up your question.  What URL are you requesting that causes the redirect?

Comment: Hello, verification is done via LDAP. It works ok if the form is provided by Spring itself. So I guess URL is not important When I put React form into action then I don't stop at the breakpoints in the LDAP verification provider - instead I just get 302 response at browser development tools